# Exchange Database Content index state: Failed

Tags: exchange-2010

We have an Exchange 2010 mailbox database with the following 'failed' state on the content index:

[image: Content index state: Failed]

Does anyone know how to fix this issue?  Is it an error of concern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Restarted service Microsoft Exchange Search Indexer.  Content index state went from status "crawling" to "healthy" after a few hours.

Answer (score 2):

I did some research on this issue and found this article http://exchangeserverpro.com/cannot-activate-database-copy-content-index-catalog-files-in-failed-state. Hope this might solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can identity the issue by checking the mailbox database copy status using following command:

Get-MailboxDatabaseCopyStatus * | sort name | Select name,status,contentindexstate

If the state shows Failed, then you need to follow below steps:

1. stop Microsoft Exchange Search and the Microsoft Exchange Search Host Controller services using services.msc. Now right-click on the service and then click on stop.
2. delete the content index from the path of Exchange database. Browse to the folder where the EDB file is stored and delete the folder with the GUID.
   [image]

3.Now start Microsoft Exchange Search and the Microsoft Exchange Search Host Controller services again. Now You will see that the database state is in healthy state.
If database is in a Database Availability Group (DAG) the [follow this link](https://www.stellarinfo.com/blog/fix-error-content-index-state-failed-and-suspended/).